# Bevel Clipping/Stopping Point?

Tags: edges, bevel, loop

Sometimes I bevel two edge loops right next to each other that will end up touching each other.  This means that when I bevel them they will eventually meet, and they will have the potential to overlap each other.  Is there like a bevel clipping option or something that will keep these from overlapping, but will allow the last bevel loops to come to the same position so I can simply click merge to remove the doubles?  Hope this makes sense.
Think similar to the clipping effect for the mirror modifier.

Comment: a simple bevel option that would keep a an edge loop from beveling too far would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can press <kbd>C</kbd> during the bevel operation to toggle between clipping or not clipping to prevent overlaps. I use this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd> shortcut for the bevel tool for a speedy workflow.

Comment: Thanks, man!  I didn't know this existed!  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is built into the Bevel Modifier, which can be used to bevel only some parts of a model using vertex groups.

[image]

Comment: Thx, that'll do it for me!

Comment: @RBlong2us I'd go with Ian's answer, because when I read your question it sounded like you were talking of using the Bevel tool in Edit mode and not the Bevel modifier.

Comment: You are correct.  However this is a good tip.